# In CSS, when declaring 'white-space: nowrap' iOS resizes font to be smaller

Tags: html, ios, css

In CSS, when declaring `white-space: nowrap` iOS resizes font to be smaller. What gives? Thanks!

Comment: Try giving font size in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

What I think it was was the viewport. Adding the following to the head, as I remember it, fixed it.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try it to be**

```css
whitespace:inherit
```

Comment: `white-space: inherit` works but I don't want to wrap text

Comment: What's happening is iOS changes the webpage width and I'm the interpreting the text to be smaller – it's zoomed out